# How do I send a key multiple times in Autohotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

I want to write an AutoHotkey script which presses a key X number of times. For example, here's a script which presses <kbd>Tab</kbd> 10 times.

```
Send, {Tab}{Tab}{Tab}{Tab}{Tab}{Tab}{Tab}{Tab}{Tab}{Tab}
```

While the above solution works, it's a bit unwieldy.

Is there a better solution for sending a key multiple times?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Try using `Send {Tab 10}`

> #### [Repeating or Holding Down a Key](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#Repeating_or_Holding_Down_a_Key)
>
> To repeat a keystroke: Enclose in braces the name of the key followed
>   by the number of times to repeat it. For example:
>
> ```
> Send {DEL 4}   ; Presses the Delete key 4 times.
> Send {S 30}    ; Sends 30 uppercase S characters.
> Send +{TAB 4}  ; Presses Shift-Tab 4 times.
> ```

***Source***: [AutoHotkey - Send / SendRaw / SendInput / SendPlay / SendEvent: Send Keys & Clicks](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#Send__SendRaw__SendInput__SendPlay__SendEvent_Send_Keys__Clicks)

---

This also works with [ControlSend](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlSend.htm) and [ControlSendRaw](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlSend.htm)

```
ControlSend, Edit1, {Enter 5}, Untitled - Notepad
```

Comment: How to parameterize the character and the number ? So that if i press "Ctrl + op + $ + 8" on a notepad, it should print "$" totally 8 times in the same line. And "Ctrl + op + # + 5" should print the character "#" totally 5 times in the same line

Comment: How would you send multiple time several keys like `^+,`?

Comment: @JinSnow You could use a loop, like in [Avatar’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50432508/3357935)

Comment: Thanks! This works: `loop 4`    `send ^+,`

Answer (score 8):

If you want the repeat in a loop, let's say every 3 seconds:

```
#a::   ; Win+a
Loop, 10
{
    SendInput {Tab}
    Sleep, 3000
}
```